# 本番デプロイで/var/www以下を公開してもセキュリティ的に大丈夫ですか？

Tags: php, laravel, security

Linux&Laravel初心者です。本番デプロイについて、セキュリティが心配です。
/var/www 以下を公開ディレクトリ？にしています。

projectName = laraprojectです。公開ディレクトリ サーバのデフォルト値の/var/www/html

ここに htmlディレクトリに ->にindex.phpなどのpublicフォルダの中身を起き
vendor類の本体を /var/www/laraproject/ に置こうとしています。

何か問題があったり、別のディレクトリに置いた方が良かったりしますでしょうか？
プロジェクトディレクトリ内のパーミッションに関しては以下の通りです。

```
storage       = rwxrwxrwx
resources     = rwxr-xr-x
composer.json = rwxrw-r-x
```

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

本番デプロイ時にセキュリティということですが、本番とはどういうレベルの本番なのでしょうか？the Internetに公開し、だれでも触れるようにするのか、たとえばイントラネットのように外部アクセス不能なネットワークに構築しているものでしょうか。
それによって話が変わりそうです。（外部公開しているサーバでotherにパーミッション下したいと考えるかどうかですが。）

> 何か問題があったり、別のディレクトリに置いた方が良かったりしますでしょうか？

これは、「どんなシステムを作りたいの？」という要件に根差した問題になります。どのぐらいのセキュリティレベルを必要としていて、そのためにどれだけのお金と時間をかけられるかという話になるので「セキュリティ大丈夫ですか？」という漠とした質問に正しくこたえられる人はいないのだろうと思います。また、パーミッションだけで達成するものでもありませんし。。。

一般的なシステム開発においては、たとえば[IPAの提供する「非機能要求グレード」](https://www.ipa.go.jp/sec/softwareengineering/std/ent03-b.html)のセキュリティ項目を参照し、そのそれぞれに要件のあるなし。あるなら具体的にどのように守るかを一つ一つ塗りつぶしていく地味な作業が必要です。（これで守られるわけではないですが、「きちんと考えていました」というポーズをとることは可能です。社会的に抹殺されないように。。）